# Use model in models.py -> fix 'django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.'

Tags: python, django

I have the following models.py code:

```
class SlackAccountMatching(models.Model):
    account         = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    organization    = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    slack_user_id   = models.CharField(default=None, null=True, max_length=50)


class SlackNotifications(models.Model):
    organization           = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slack_notification_name = models.CharField(default=None, null=True, max_length=255)
    slack_notification_time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.time(16, 00))
```

Below in the same file I want to use both `SlackNotifications` and `SlackAccountMatching` to make queries in the respective model. I was looking into the [ready()][1] and therefore am doing:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class SlackApplicationConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'slack_application'

    def ready(self):
        from .models import SlackAccountMatching, SlackNotifications
```

However, the error is still showing up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/slack_application/models.py", line 455, in <module>
    SlackNotifications.objects.filter(organization_id=1).values('slack_notification_time')
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 941, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "//venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1396, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1415, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1289, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1115, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1519, in names_to_path
    if field.is_relation and not field.related_model:
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 95, in related_model
    apps.check_models_ready()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 141, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you.
[1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready

Comment: show the whole traceback please

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko added above...

Comment: @manfredobelugo Where exactly do you write this line `SlackNotifications.objects.filter(organization_id=1).values('slack_notification_time')`? Also is that app config _inside_ `models.py`???

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes, it is inside models.py

Comment: anyone able to help?

Comment: That query mentioned in comment above is executed too early before the app registry is ready (as you can see in the traceback). Move the query elsewhere where it wont be triggered that early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ready" function should contain the code you want to execute also (and remove it from models.py):

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class SlackApplicationConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'slack_application'

    def ready(self):
        from .models import SlackAccountMatching, SlackNotifications
        some_notifications = SlackNotifications.objects.filter(
            organization_id=1
        ).values('slack_notification_time')
        print(some_notifications)
```

but I think this will not be useful to you (as far as I understand), I would recommend to not do this kind of logic in the models.py file.
Maybe you can explain what is the goal to put this in the models.py file?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have now moved the model to another models.py file of another django app, however, I still have the same error... does that make sense? I thought it originally was there because I defined the model and called it in the same file...

Comment: Django has time to load the models when starting the server, so it's normal that you get this kind of error if you call Models inside models.py of any app. This kind of logic you want to add is usually set in views.py or admin.py. So you do the filter for some specific view.